# How non-projective can a complete variety be?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a positive integer $n$, can you give an example of a connected smooth proper $\mathbb{C}$-scheme such that any $n$ closed points are contained in a common affine open, but there is $n+1$ closed points that are not contained in a common affine open? What is the minimum dimension of such an example (probably larger than 2, because every smooth proper surface is projective)?

Comment: Do you know examples for any n? How about n=1?

Comment: @Asvin me personally, no. Do you? The Wikipedia seems to be more knowledgeable (no pun intended, I just did not check in detail. And mistakes there do happen with a non-negligible frequency): "For quasi-projective varieties, it is obvious that any finite subset is contained in an open affine subvariety. This property fails for Hironaka's example: a two-points set consisting of a point in each of the exceptional curves is not contained in any open affine subvariety."

Comment: I vaguely remembered that Hironakas example did work for n = 2. Thanks for confirming. Maybe one can think about extending his example for any n?

Comment: maybe so, that is the question in some sense.

Answer (score 10):

For every positive integer $n$, Farnik has constructed a smooth complete variety over an algebraically closed field with $n=\mathrm{sup}\{$$m$: every $m$ points of in $X$ are contained in a common affine open subset of $X\}$. The construction suggests that the varieties are threefolds so the minimum dimension appears to be $3$.

M. Farnik, *On strengthening of the Kleiman-Chevalley criterion*, Proceedings of the AMS 141 no 11 (2013) pp 4005-4013, doi:10.1090/S0002-9939-2013-11695-3. [Link at AMS site](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2013-141-11/S0002-9939-2013-11695-3/).

Comment: These are by construction varieties birationally equivalent to $\mathbf{P}^3$, over an arbitrary algebraically closed field.